# Violation of Law of Demeter in Interactors/Use Cases/Application Services

Tags: unit-testing, oop, domain-driven-design, use-case

Lately I have been looking through a bunch of ideas for software architecture. What I see is that a lot of them converge into having Use Cases/Interactors (Clean Architecture) or Application Services (DDD) as an entry point to our applications.

I really like the idea, but something has been bothering me.

Both ways the user injects the repository, which you use to fetch the domain entities and perform an action on it. Like this:

```
class Interactor
  def initialize(repository)
    @repository = repository
  end

  def call(entity_id)
    entity = @repository.find(entity_id)
    entity.do_something
  end
end
```

If I want to test this in isolation, I need to return a mock from `@repository.find`, which already is a mock. That is not good and tells me that I am violating the Law of Demeter (which is the case).

Also, this is too procedural, which bothers me.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I would like to just add that from the current example you have shown here you are just violating [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) by having this class doing more than one thing. I would also take this opportunity to rework this class as converting it to a Query, have an other Command that could call the `do_something()` function, so then you adhere to the [Command-Query Separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation) pattern and both SRP. Later you could compose othe decorators to this implementation..

Comment: .. But it's really just shooting in the dark without seeing more details.

Comment: I read once that this is not a violation of SRP because the reason for this class to change is only a change of the Business Rule. I actually agree with that. I left the example abstract enough on purpose because this happens many times.

Comment: Put it simple: whenever you are changing the observable state of the system (with `do_something()` call) and then in the same place you query for data via the `find()` method you are doing _two_ pretty different actions and therefore you don't only do one thing in this class. Business Rule should be inside the entity not in a command or query...

Comment: I am sorry when I said business rule. But I meant application rule. The Domain should contain all the Biz Rules. But stuff like sending emails, persisting are application specific rules and should be in the application layer (which contain the interactors). This will change only if the application rule change.

Answer (score 4):

> That is not good and tells me that I am violating the Law of Demeter (which is the case).

How so?

The Law of Demeter is summarized and paraphrased in a variety of ways, but for simplicity let's just look at the small list [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter):

> - Each unit should have only limited knowledge about other units: only units "closely" related to the current unit.
> - Each unit should only talk to its friends; don't talk to strangers.
> - Only talk to your immediate friends.

So in what way does the code shown violate this law?  `Interactor` has knowledge of exactly two things, a particular repository and a particular entity.  Its knowledge of the repository is a technical concern, and it uses that interaction to get an instance of an entity.  And its knowledge of the entity is a business concern, and it uses that interaction to perform a business operation.

On any domain graph or chart or whiteboard drawing, `Interactor` would be expected to have a direct connection to both of these units.  And indeed it does.  It doesn't reach into those units to have knowledge of *their* neighbors, it just has knowledge of its own neighbors and interacts only with them.

So... What exactly is the problem?

As a purely technical concern you may be able to inject the entity directly instead of injecting the repository.  There isn't enough information about the system represented in the question to really list any pros and cons there.  But that's not a question of the Law of Demeter, that's just an implementation concern of dependency management.

Unit testing requires that you create two mocks, sure.  But this unit interacts with two units.  So that's a given, really.

Comment: `Interactor` doesn't have knoledge of the entity. I am not injecting the entity directly on it. I can easily replace my code to `@repository.find(entity_id).do_something`, this way becomes clearer that I am violating Demeter. I made an abstract example because things like this happens all the time (except when I am creating entities).

Comment: The Mock returning Mock on the tests also makes that clear I think.

Comment: Comment after the edit :) There is no problem to interact with two components. The problem is that you are interacting with a component returned by another one.

Comment: @Thiago: What makes you think it doesn't have knowledge of the entity?  It exposes a business operation which *specifically* interacts with the entity.  Is there some reason it shouldn't interact with the entity?  If so, why does it?  What is the `call` method meant to do if not invoke a business operation on the entity?  The proposed code change in that comment still just interacts with exactly these two units, which isn't a Demeter violation.  It's not clear why `Interactor` *shouldn't* be interacting with the entity, maybe there's some business context you can clarify?

Comment: also from Wikipedia: "More formally, the Law of Demeter for functions requires that a method `m` of an object O may only invoke the methods of the following kinds of objects:[2]

* `O` itself
* `m`'s parameters
* Any objects created/instantiated within `m`
* `O`'s direct component objects
* A global variable, accessible by `O`, in the scope of `m`"

The entity is none of those.

Comment: @Thiago: I think this is reading too much into the letter of the law while ignoring the intent of the law.  The intent can be demonstrated on a whiteboard drawing of the domain.  If A and B are connected, then A can interact with B.  It doesn't really matter that A gets an instance of B from C.  A could just as easily have *created* an instance of B, but for unrelated reasons B is created by a factory instead of direct instantiation.

Comment: I get your point. I agree with it. Testing it still bothers me, though. I am gonna look into it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Thiago What's hard to test? There's just one mock in there... the repository. I hope you aren't mocking domain objects, are you?

Comment: @plalx, if I want to test in isolation I have to, don't I?

Comment: @Thiago No you don't. What do you want to test if not domain logic? By having too many mocks you will end up having to write tests for your tests ;) Why would you ever want to mock a domain object?

Comment: Because my intention is to unit test every component. The domain object will have his own tests.